# Can I use histogram matching to harmonize two sensors data? (SPOT and Planet)

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, histogram

I have to image collections of SPOT (airbus) and Planet.
The images are not overlapped (from different locations) and are not from the same dates. However they have RGB-NIR.
I would like to be able to compare Planet image to SPOT image , creating "harmonized" dataset.
I have read the [histogram matching](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/histogram-matching) tutorial and it seems like what they do there is kind of harmonization, however, it seems like they can do it only of two images are overlapped and that the process is more simple , compared to ,for example. [the Landsat-sentinel HLS project](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425718304139#bb0240)  (Claverie, M., Ju, J., Masek, J. G., Dungan, J. L., Vermote, E. F., Roger, J.-C., Skakun, S. V., & Justice, C. (2018). The Harmonized Landsat and Sentinel-2 surface reflectance data set. Remote Sensing of Environment, 219, 145-161.) .

**My question is,
is it possible to use the histogram matching to combine two datasets of planet and spot?Or should I search for other methods?**

Comment: Here is a tutorial on histogram matching in Earth Engine: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/histogram-matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are looking for.
If you just want to match the images in a dispaying goal, you could do this.

However, if you want to scientifically align your images, you have to go through the complicated HLS pipeline to correct:

- differences in the sensor bandwidth for each band
- differences in the viewing angle
- differences in the sun elevation as the images are not taken at the same time and the same height

... and lot of other differences.